# Unreached cases affect switch-case performance

Tags: c++, switch-statement

In C++, I have an inline function which contains a switch-case statement. I found that when some **specific case** branch is programmed, the time cost of the program increases significantly, even though the **specific case** was never hit during the runtime.

---

A code sample is shown here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum Types {
    T0 = 0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, TS, TA, TB, TC
};

int64_t special(int64_t num, string str) {
    char buf[16];
    buf[0] = (num % 10) + '0';
    buf[1] = (num % 10) + '0';
    buf[2] = str.c_str()[0];
    return atoi(buf);
}

inline int64_t common(int64_t base, int64_t num) {
    return num + base;
}

inline int64_t myfunc(Types t, int64_t num) {
    string str;
    switch (t) {
    case T0:
        return 0;
        break;
#define CASE_TYPE(tv, base) \
    case tv: \
        return common(base, num); \
        break;
    CASE_TYPE(T1, 1)
    CASE_TYPE(T2, 2)
    CASE_TYPE(T3, 3)
    CASE_TYPE(T4, 4)
    CASE_TYPE(T5, 5)
    CASE_TYPE(T6, 6)
    CASE_TYPE(T7, 7)
    CASE_TYPE(T8, 8)
    CASE_TYPE(T9, 9)
#undef CASE_TYPE
    case TS:
        // Comment out the following 3 lines increases performance
        str = string((char*)&num, 4);
        return special(num, str);
        break;
        // Comment out the above 3 lines increases performance
    case TA:
    case TB:
    case TC:
        return 0;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

static const int LoopNum = 1000000000;

static inline int64_t now() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (int64_t)tv.tv_sec * 1000 + (int64_t)tv.tv_usec / 1000;
}


// execution command line: ./test 1 1
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Types t = (Types)atoi(argv[1]); // t = T1
    int64_t num = (int64_t)atoi(argv[2]); // t = 1
    int64_t total = 0;
    int64_t start = now();
    for (int i = 0; i < LoopNum; i++) {
        total += myfunc(t, num);
    }
    cout << "Time Cost: " << now() - start << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "Result: " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, when the lines in `case TS` block are comment out, the performance increases a lot:

- **With** `case TS` block: Time Cost = **2250 ms**
- **Without** `case TS` block: Time Cost = **1492 ms**

The program is compiled and executed with command: `g++ -o test -O2 test.cpp && ./test 1 1`. With this command, the variable values in the program are `t = T1` and `num = 1`.

Tested on `Windows Subsystem for linux (Ubuntu 18.04)` with `g++ 7.4.0`.

---

What is confusing is that, this problem doesn't always emerges. I have no clear knowledge about how to write such code (but the above example really emerges this problem).

According to my tests, it seems that the problem will emerge under some of these conditions:

- The program in the **specific case** is complicated. E.g. when the program contains remote process calling.
- The **specific case** is not the last case, or the case value is not the largest value in the enum.

---

I really don't have any idea how this happens and how to avoid it. Can anyone give any adivce? Either the mechanism or a work-around will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You have at least two problems in the code that leads to *undefined behavior*. First you can't cast an integer to a string; And second you use string functions on arrays that doesn't have an explicit string null-terminator.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Thanks. But please ignore these problems. I just want to add some complete logics to reproduce my problem. As the operations about strings are never executed, as I mentioned, the potential risks are not a problem. Of course, these problems must be noticed in real programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the disassembly on Compiler Explorer, the difference is that when you comment out the code for `case TS`, you remove all uses of the local `str` string variable.  The compiler completely removes it, and the resulting code is much simpler (as there are no possible calls to the constructor or destructor, and in particular to delete to free the string's memory).  The simplified code is small enough to fit in the processor's Loop Stream Detector (LSD).  The LSD can greatly improve the performance of tight loops as the repeating instructions stay resident in the Instruction Queue, avoiding the use of the front end pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful! Do you have any idea of how to improve the performance while keeping the specific case containing string operations? One of my ideas is to call another non-inline function which implements those operations. So that I don't have any string operations (including constructing/destructing) in the inline function. This solution seems to be useful in some situations. But in some other situations (in which the calling logics are more complicated), the problem still remains.... How can I make certain that my program runs as fast as those without specific cases?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to inspect disassembler of your program. My guess is that the compiler picks a different strategy for implementing the `switch` statement, which is less efficient for your case.

As a workaround, you may want to investigate which cases are more likely to be hit and which are less so and separate the "hot" cases and the "cold" ones into different `switch`/`case` blocks and select the right one with an upper-level `if`.